# pip-install Python Package from Azure Artefact on a Databricks Cluster

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, pip

I have a small demo package that I've published my to Azure Devops - I'm able to pip install this locally by spinning up a virtual environment and adding the specific global setting to my `pip.conf` file.

Now, I want to install this into my databricks cluster - I've been unable to find any documentation to do so.

Things to note, this databricks cluster is not within the same tenant as my devops. I've created a token and given it access to read packages within my devops.

I assume I need to add my token & username somewhere in my artifact index url and install it in the cluster PyPi area?

however I can't figure this out

```
pip install mypackage==0.01 https://tokenname:tokenpassword@pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/mypackage/_packaging/mypackage/pypi/simple/
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

in the screenshot you've provided for installing libraries in the cluster, you just have to input
**Package: mypackage==0.01**

mypackage is the package name of the library. 0.01 is the version

**Repository: https://tokenname:tokenpassword@pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/mypackage/_packaging/mypackage/pypi/simple/**

you just need to put the token name here and the rest of the repository where your package lives

Comment: has anyone tested this? no longer on Azure (AWS/GCP shop at the mo) - don't have access to a dev tenancy to test.

Comment: This works but without the `tokenname:` part. Just the token itself suffices