# Install Python Package from Azure Artifacts on Databricks Using Python File

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-databricks

I have a Python package in a feed on Azure DevOps Artifacts. I want to be able to install this on Databricks using a Python file. How do I do this? Can I do something like a `pip install ..`?

Up to this point, the process we have been following is to release the corresponding `.whl` file to the Databricks workspace, through a Azure Pipeline and use it from there, however, this will not work for my current use case.

I want to be able to install a particular version of my package using a Python file that has been stored in the DBFS file system. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pip-install Python Package from Azure Artefact on a Databricks Cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66631267/pip-install-python-package-from-azure-artefact-on-a-databricks-cluster)

Comment: [Databricks CI/CD using Azure DevOps](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/databricks-ci-cd-using-azure-devops-part-i-ci-e9cacd89b6c2), [Install custom Python Libraries from private PyPI on Databricks](https://towardsdatascience.com/install-custom-python-libraries-from-private-pypi-on-databricks-6a7669f6e6fd) and [How to install a python package from azure artifact feed to databricks and kubernetes](https://serverfault.com/questions/993238/how-to-install-a-python-package-from-azure-artifact-feed-to-databricks-and-kuber)

Comment: @DeepDave-MT The first question relates to how the package can be installed using the UI, right? I want to be able to install it within a Python script: similar to how you would do `!pip install ..` in a notebook. I don't quite understand the answer in the second question, to be honest.

Comment: Basically, my entire process needs to be automated. I want to have a Python script in Databricks that will be called by an ADF pipeline on a schedule. This script will also be released to Databricks using a CICD pipeline. I want to have the option of using any version of my package within my script. This parameter will be passed through ADF. That is why it needs to be installed at the  point that the script is called.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Libraries API` to install and uninstall libraries in Databricks' Cluster.

> The `Libraries API` allows you to install and uninstall libraries and get the status of libraries on a cluster.

Mention cluster name, packages and source in `install-libraries.json` as shown in below example.

```
{
  "cluster_id": "10201-my-cluster",
  "libraries": [
    {
      "jar": "dbfs:/mnt/libraries/library.jar"
    },
    {
      "egg": "dbfs:/mnt/libraries/library.egg"
    },
    {
      "whl": "dbfs:/mnt/libraries/mlflow-0.0.1.dev0-py2-none-any.whl"
    },
    {
      "whl": "dbfs:/mnt/libraries/wheel-libraries.wheelhouse.zip"
    },
    {
      "maven": {
        "coordinates": "org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.2",
        "exclusions": ["slf4j:slf4j"]
      }
    },
    {
      "pypi": {
        "package": "simplejson",
        "repo": "https://my-pypi-mirror.com"
      }
    },
    {
      "cran": {
        "package": "ada",
        "repo": "https://cran.us.r-project.org"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Then, write a bash script executing json file and installing mentioned libraries in Databricks workspace.

```
curl --netrc --request POST \
https://<databricks-instance>/api/2.0/libraries/install \
--data @install-libraries.json
```

Replace:

- `<databricks-instance>` with the Databricks workspace instance name, for example dbc-a1b2345c-d6e7.cloud.databricks.com.

Source: [Libraries API 2.0](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/libraries.html#install)

Comment: How would I edit the JSON file to be able to install packages, not from PyPI, but from a feed that I have created in Azure DevOps Artifacts?